# Adding number in a CSV in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

How can you add numbers in a CSV in XSLT 1 ?

I want to take:

`<num>1,2,3</num>`

and get the sum of the numbers in the element, so we would get 6 from the above.

Answer (score 0):

**Using FXSL and the `str-split-to-words` template (I am lazy to write recursive templates which is time consuming and error-prone `:)`  )**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
          <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="','"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:variable name="vNums" select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*"/>

       <xsl:value-of select="sum($vNums)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<num>1,2,3</num>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
6
```